# Java version 6 revision 22 repeatedly asks to be installed

Tags: windows-7, installation, java, version

I have no idea how many times Java version 6 revision 22 has asked me to install it.  I've lost count.  What's wrong with it?  Why doesn't it install properly and leave me alone?

This is on a Windows 7 machine.

Comment: For those super users out there, is this On-Topic for here?

Answer (score 3):

This is a long shot, but your problem could be you are installing the 32bit version on a 64bit os.

Try uninstalling the 32 bit Java Update version and installing the 64 bit one.

Comment: That's a very good idea.  I'll try it when I get home.

Comment: This is not the case. I've deployed 32-bit Java to many 64-bit machines flawlessly including this specified update. Most people don't make use of the 64-bit Internet Explorer and the regular IE will search for 32-bit Java plugins, hence why I install the 32-bit version instead.

Answer (score 1):

Check the application event log for clues. If all else fails, uninstall all previous versions of Java and then **only reinstall** Java 6 rev 22.

Comment: Hey, is this type of question appropriate for SU?

Comment: @jjn it's about computer software, I don't see a problem?

Comment: neither do I.  But I'm careful to migrate things to Super User because I don't want it to be SO's dumping ground.

Answer (score 0):

You might try disabling UAC, then uninstal as administrator and reinstall again.